# How to get details for the values found in the justification list from the score director in OptaPlanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm working on parsing the data from the ScoreDirector to display in my GUI and I wonder how does the **getJustificationList()** works so I can reliably display the data in a String.

Here is some context of application:

```
rule "The max duration per day must be met"
    when
    $contract : Contract()
    $day : Day()
    $totalDuration : Integer() from accumulate(
        ScheduleTime(
            timeGrain != null,
            timeGrain.day != null,
            contract == $contract,
            getDayOfYear() == $day.getDayOfYear(),
            $scheduleTimeDuration : getGrainDuration()
        ),
        sum($scheduleTimeDuration)
    )
    then
      scoreHolder.penalize(kcontext, Math.abs($totalDuration - $contract.getRequiredGrainPerDay()));
end
```

When I execute this piece of code

```java
for (ConstraintMatch match : constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintMatchSet()) {
    if (((HardMediumSoftScore) match.getScore()).getHardScore() != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < match.getJustificationList().size(); i ++){
            System.out.println(
                i+". " +
                match.getJustificationList().get(i).getClass().getName() +
                " => " +
                match.getJustificationList().get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

It ouputs this:

```
0. java.lang.Integer => 0
1. domain.Day => 2019-Jun-01
2. domain.Contract => Contract for Bernadine Swift
0. java.lang.Integer => 0
1. domain.Day => 2019-May-26
2. domain.Contract => Contract for Charles Schwarzeneger
...
```

From my examples above, it seems like the order is related to the order the variables are created in the drools rule backward.

What determines the order in which the values are going to appear in the list and how can I make sure that when I'm reaching for index 2, it's going be the Contract object and not something else?

**Edit**
Here is the version of optaplanner used: **7.21.0.Final**

Comment: Good question. This API contract is poor indeed. Something we need to investigate in the future.
Anyway,  I suspect the reversing is caused by me doing an extra reverse because drools used to reverse their list, but now doesn't.

Comment: No, I don't do the reverse any more:
https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/holder/AbstractScoreHolder.java#L133 so that means that drools delivers them reversed maybe

Comment: So if I understand, this is an issue related to drools and not Optaplanner?